# Is it possible to get shell properties for an item not in the shell namespace?

Tags: powershell, winapi, ipropertystorage

### Short Version

How does the shell get the properties of a file?

### Long Version

The Windows Shell exposes a rich system of properties about items (e.g. files and folders) in the shell namespace.

For example:

- **System.Title**: A Quick Guide for SQL Server Native Client  OLE DB to ODBC Conversion
- **System.Author**: George Yan (KW)
- **System.Document.LastAuthor**: rohanl
- **System.Comment**: To learn more about this speaker, find other TEDTalks, and subscribe to this Podcast series, visit www.TED.com   Feedback: tedtalks@ted.com
- **System.ItemParticipants**: George Yan (KW)
- **System.Company**: Contoso
- **System.Language**: English (United States)
- **System.Document.DateCreated**: 6/‎10/‎2014 ‏‎5∶16∶30 ᴘᴍ
- **System.Image.HorizontalSize**: 1845 pixels
- **System.Image.VerticalSize**: 4695 pixels
- **System.Image.HorizontalResolution**: 71 dpi
- **System.Image.VerticalResolution**: 71 dpi

In order for the shell to read these properties, it obviously has to use a lot of sources:

- [Windows Media Foundation IMFMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/metadata-providers-in-windows-vista) works great for images and movies
- Windows Imaging Component (**WIC**) probably has a lot of APIs for reading metadata
- I'm not sure if **`IFilter`** can retrieve **Title**, **Author**, **Subject**, **Comments** etc from Office documents

Either way, it has to read the file contents stream and do something with the contents of the file in order to get all these fancy shell properties.  In other words:

```
IStream  \
   +      |--> [magic] --> IPropertyStore
 .ext    /
```

### Can use it with my own stream?

I have items that are not in the shell namespace; they are in a data store. I do expose them to the shell through `IDataObject` as [**`CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/clipboard) with an **`IStream`** when its time to perform copy-paste or drag-drop. But outside of that they are just streamable blobs in a data store.

I'd like to be able to leverage all the existing work done by the very talented and hard-working<sup>[1](https://youtu.be/1k9IlR3-_-A?t=21)</sup> shell team to read metadata from a *"file"*, which in the end only exists as an `IStream`.

Is there perhaps a binding context option that lets me *get a property store* based on an `IDataObject` rather than a `IShellItem2`?

So rather than:

```
IPropertyStore ps = shellItem2.GetPropertyStore();
```

is there a:

```
IPropertyStore ps = GetShellPropertiesFromFileStream(stream);
```

?

How does the shell get all the properties of a file?

### Bonus Chatter - [IPropertyStoreFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/propsys/nn-propsys-ipropertystorefactory)

> This interface is typically obtained through [IShellFolder::BindToObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/5e699494-1974-4b9b-8324-9394f7b96fe4) or [IShellItem::BindToHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fadd70cd-5018-4b71-af7b-d9c780ebddc5). **It is useful for data source implementers who want to avoid the additional overhead of creating a property store through [IShellItem2::GetPropertyStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/706b2551-a9b0-4368-babb-e54cea6d297e)**. However, **IShellItem2::GetPropertyStore** is the recommended method to obtain a property store unless you are implementing a data source through a Shell folder extension.

### Tried

```
IPropertyStore ps = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PropertyStore);
IInitializeWithStream iws = ps.QueryInterface(IID_IInitializeWithStream);
```

But `CLSID_PropertyStore` does not support `IInitializeWithStream`.

### Bonus Reading

- MSDN: [Initializing Property Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/building-property-handlers-property-handlers)

  > Property handlers are a crucial part of the property system. They are **invoked in-process by the indexer to read and index property values, and are also invoked by Windows Explorer in-process to read and write property values directly in the files.**
- MSDN: [Registering and Distributing Property Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/prophand-reg-dist) *(spellunking the registry for fun and reading contracts from the other side)*

Comment: `CoCreateInstance` to create an `IPropertyStore` then query for `IInitializeWithStream` maybe. Not tried it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Have some experience in Property Store handlers) How I see a solution:

1. Get PropertyStore handler CLSID for your file extension. You should use 2 regkeys key:

   - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertyHandlers\.yourext`
   - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\SystemPropertyHandlers`
2. Create two objects with CoCreateInstance
3. If you have 2 object you can combine them into single object with **[PSCreateMultiplexPropertyStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/propsys/nf-propsys-pscreatemultiplexpropertystore)**
4. Query for **[IInitializeWithStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/propsys/nn-propsys-iinitializewithstream)** (also you can try to query **[IPersistStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ipersiststream)**).

If the PropertyStore object supports **IInitializeWithStream**/**IPersistStream**: you are lucky - just init your object and query the properties you need. If does not - you still have (dirty) variant to create temporary file and then use **[IPersistFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ipersistfile)**.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for pointing out the **PSCreateMultiplexPropertyStore** helper, as well as pointing **both** stream initialization interfaces. And thanks for pointing out the hack of saving to a temp file. Very complete answer!